# How to Join two tables on two separate variables with one variable having the same name

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what I have so far. I'm trying to join these two tables and if I do not use a using() function, then SQL tells me there is an invalid relational operator just simply using an ON. However using a "using" also throws an error that I did not end it properly. Any help would be nice, thanks.

```
DROP TABLE JOINED_TABLE;
CREATE TABLE JOINED_TABLE AS

SELECT *
FROM
H_SAMPLE50 H
INNER JOIN D_SAMPLE50 D
USING(ID_NBR)
AND(H.PULL_DATE = D.PREV_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.  One is `where`:

```
SELECT *
FROM H_SAMPLE50 H INNER JOIN
     D_SAMPLE50 D
     USING (ID_NBR)
WHERE H.PULL_DATE = D.PREV_DATE;
```

The other is `ON`:

```
SELECT *
FROM H_SAMPLE50 H INNER JOIN
     D_SAMPLE50 D
     ON H.ID_NBR = D.ID_NBR AND H.PULL_DATE = D.PREV_DATE;
```

Think of `USING` as a short-hand to handle the case where *all* the `JOIN` keys have the same name.  If this is not the case, then just use `ON`.

Comment: So with the ON option I am actually getting an error of "duplicate column name" for the ID_NBR

Comment: @Thesystem32 . . . You should not get that with a simple `SELECT`.  But just select the columns that you want.  Or, if you need the same column name from both tables, give the columns unique aliases.